# How to update certain group of values in single column using SQL

Tags: python, google-bigquery, sql-update, sqldatatypes

I'm brand new in python and updating tables using sql. I would like to ask how to update certain group of values in single column using SQL. Please see example below:

| id |
| --- |
| 123 |
| 999991234 |
| 235 |
| 789 |
| 200 |
| 999993456 |

I need to add the missing prefix '99999' to the records without '99999'. The id column has integer data type by default. I've tried the sql statement, but I have a conflict between data types that's I've tried with cast statement:

```
update tablename
set id = concat('99999', cast(id as string))
where id not like '99999%';
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? `concat()` suggests that it's MySQL, and it will automatically convert the string to an integer.

Comment: `SET id = CONCAT('99999', id)`

Comment: ```
UPDATE tablename 
SET id = CONCAT('99999', id) 
WHERE id NOT LIKE '99999%';
```

Would work in any recent version mysql

Comment: I'm using BigQuery @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use the [`LIKE` operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#operator_precedence) and [`CONCAT()` function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#concat), the column data type should be a `STRING` or `BYTE`. In this case, you would need to cast the `WHERE` clause condition as well as the value of the `SET` statement.

Using your sample data:

[image]

Ran this update script:

```
UPDATE mydataset.my_table
SET id =  CAST(CONCAT('99999', CAST(id AS STRING)) AS INTEGER) 
WHERE CAST(id as STRING) NOT LIKE '99999%'
```

Result:

[image]

Rows were updated successfully and the table ended up with this data:

[image]

Comment: I was so close with my statement, thanks!

Comment: Hi @nerd, I'm glad it answered your question. Please accept the answer, that way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?